# IDE producing syntax error on code snippet

Tags: jquery

My IDE is reporting a syntax error with the below statement and according to the documentation there is nothing wrong with it. I've tried every combination of characters that I can.

This is the statement, all I'm looking for is a `span` with an `id` that starts with `question`:

```
$("span[name^='question']").click(function(){
  alert('test')
});
```

Comment: You're not looking for a span with an id but for a span with a name attribute starting with question. Would be worthwhile including what the IDE error is. Error and Warnings are two different things and I'm going to guess you're getting a warning.

Comment: And what the IDE is.

Comment: I'm going to guess Visual Studio.

Comment: That seems a perfectly valid js/jquery code.

Comment: $('#question1').hide(); //this works
$('id[id^=question]').hide();//this doesn't

Comment: IDE is zend Studio